# How do I prove this measure of entropy is constant?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, information-theory, entropy

This actually came about from a different question: "A random natural number $0 \leq n \leq 999$ is chosen and written down in base 10 by person A (including leading zeros, if $n<100$). Person B then writes down a three-digit number $m$ (also including any necessary leading zeroes) and sees how many, if any, of the digits match $n$. What is the associated entropy of the set of matches?"

We can calculate these probabilities fairly easily. There is a .001 chance that $m=n$. There is then a .009 chance that the first two digits match but the third does not, a .009 chance for the second two match but the first does not, and a .009 chance for the first and last to match but not the middle; in total, there is a .027 chance that two digits match. We can use a similar argument to see that there is a .243 probability that one digit matches, and a .729 probability that no digits match. The entropy function in its general form (when measured in bits) is equal to $H=\Sigma_i^np_i\log_2 (\frac{1}{p_i})$, where $p_i$ is a the probability that a certain outcome occurs. Thus, our entropy is

- $\frac{1}{1000}\log_2{(1000)}+\frac{27}{1000}\log_2{(\frac{1000}{9})}+\frac{243}{1000}\log_2{(\frac{1000}{81})}+\frac{729}{1000}\log_2{(\frac{1000}{243})}\approx 1.407$

One quickly sees that this can be generalized for $10^b$ with the following formula

$$H(X_b)=\Sigma_{n=0}^b {b \choose n}\left(\frac{9^n}{10^b}\right)\log_2{\left(\frac{10^b}{9^n}\right)}$$

Here's where things get interesting: I was looking at this through Desmos, and I found the following relation.

### $\frac{\log_2{(10^b)}}{H(X_b)} = 7.083068882...$

This seems to hold for natural $b$ - there is some small variance from this value when $b\in \{\mathbb{R^+}\}/\{\mathbb{N}\}$, but I am more astonished at this constant appearing out of the blue. I can't find anything on OEIS suggesting that this is a known constant. Where did it come from, and what is its exact form?

Comment: If the value is supposed to be the entropy of the number of digits where they match, then there should be binomials in the inside the logarithms. What you’ve calculated is the entropy of the set of matches.

Comment: So it should be $$H(X_b)=\Sigma_{n=0}^b {b \choose n}(\frac{9^n}{10^b})\log_2{\left(\frac{10^b}{\binom bn9^n}\right)}$$

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! I will edit my question to reflect the fact that this is about the entropy of the set of matches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More generallly, if you have a coin with probability of heads $p$ and you flip it $b$ times, the entropy of the locations of the heads is $$-\sum \binom bn p^n(1-p)^{b-n}\log\left(p^n(1-p)^{b-n}\right)\\=-\log(p)\sum_n n\binom bnp^n(1-p)^{b-n}\\-\log(1-p)\sum(b-n)\binom bn p^n(1-p)^{b-n}$$
Then $$n\binom bn=b\binom{b-1}{n-1}\\(b-n)\binom nb=b\binom{b-1}{n}.$$ So you’d get an entropy of $$-b(p+(1-p))^{b-1}\log p +(-b)(p+(1-p))^{b-1}\log(1-p)\\=-b (p\log p+(1-p)\log (1-p)),$$ or $b$ times the entropy of a single toss of the coin.

In your case, $p=\frac1{10},$ so $$H(X_b)=b\left(\frac1{10}\log(10)+\frac{9}{10}\log\left(\frac{10}9\right)\right)\\=b\left(\log(10)-\frac{9}{10}\log9\right)$$

Then $$\frac{\log(10^b)}{H(X_b)}=\frac{\log(10)}{\log 10-\frac9{10}\log 9}=\frac{1}{1-\frac{9}{10}\log_{10}9}$$

---

This is a special case of the additive nature of entropy. If you have two independent random events with probabilities $p_i$ and $q_j$ then the entropy of both events is the sum of the entropies of the individual events.

$$\begin{align} 
-\sum_{ij} p_iq_j\log (p_iq_j)&=-\sum_{ij}q_{j}p_i\log p_i-\sum_{ij}p_iq_j\log q_j\\&=-\left(\sum_j q_j\right)\sum_i p_i\log p_i-\left(\sum_i p_i\right)\sum_j q_j\log q_j\\&=-\sum_i p_i\log p_i-\sum_j q_j\log q_j.\end{align}$$